# Shared Project indicator for Universal Apps

Tags: c#

In a Shared Project, how do I detect a Universal platform (Windows Store/Phone). What would be the equivalent to **IOS**, **ANDROID**, etc. Do I need to define my own?

Answer (score 0):

For windows phone and windows store app Inside Universal App in Shared folder the coding is done

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
        //your code for windows phone
#endif
       //your code for windows store app
```